# OpenGL Mis-Matched Lines between Objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I have been drawing some basic textured objects with OpenGL. However, when these cubes are placed next to each other, these distorted lines form between them. They also become more visible as I rotate my objects. What could be causing this?

Some Pictures:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

I have also tried running it with `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE)`, but it is still the same as in the pictures.

Also, there is NO space between the cubes.

Comment: Some clarifying questions: are you using alpha blending?  Is the cube vertex that's in the center of your image shared by all four cubes (i.e., there's no space between your cubes).

Comment: Assuming your cubes are touching perfectly (*ie* no floating-point precision errors in the transformation), you might consider experimenting with your `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` parameters to extend the texture past the edges of the texture coords, in case the coords are cutting off exactly at the edge.

Comment: My glDepthFunc is GL_LEQUAL, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: paddy I have enabled used both **GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T** and **GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S**  `glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP);`

Comment: My guess is anti-aliasing artifacts.

Comment: You probably want `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. Make sure you properly learn what the texture wrap modes actually do.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single pixel strip, as it looks like in these images, then it's probably due to polygon antialiasing.  Turn off polygon antialiasing and hopefully it will go away.  Polygon antialiasing only works in certain scenarios, and does not work well if you have multiple polygons meeting like this.

If it's a texturing issue, it will become more obvious as you zoom in closer to the object, and either REPEAT or CLAMP_TO_EDGE should resolve this, but it looks like you have tried some of the texturing options already.